# .NET Regex Not working as it should

Tags: .net, regex, validation

I have the following regex pattern: (.NET 1.1 Regex Validator)

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])[a-zA-Z0-9@\\-_\\+\\.]{6,32}$
```

I need to meet the following requirements:

6 to 32 characters 
must contain at least one letter. 
Allowed characters are 
letters `(a-z, A-Z)`, 
numbers `(0-9)`, 
`@` ("at" symbol), 
`.` (period), 
`_` (underscore), 
`+` (plus), 
`-` (minus).

Any entries starting with numeric values, seem to be 'skipped' until non numeric values are encountered.

`123abc` fails
`123abcde` fails
`123abcdef` passes

So I see that it's 'counting' the look ahead AFTER the numeric values, why?

Thanks.

Comment: Your regular expression looks fine to me, and it works here in .NET 3.5 testing with Regex.Match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite possible that it's a bug in .NET 1.1. All of your "fail" examples work using [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/), which is based on Silverlight which uses the .NET 2.0 Regex implementation.

You might try using a positive *look-behind* assertion instead and see if that gets around the problem:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9@\-_\+\.]{6,32}(?<=.*[A-Za-z])$
```

**Edit:** Considering this is an ASP.NET validator, you should double check that it's not failing client validation (javascript). Some advanced features (like zero-width look ahead/behinds) are not supported by some browsers.

Try to disable client side validation by setting `EnableClientScript` to `false` on the `RegularExpressionValidator` and see if that fixes the problem. If it does, then it's a browser support issue and I'd recommend splitting your validation into two:

1. `^[a-zA-Z0-9@\-_\+\.]{6,32}$ # must be 6-32 characters`
2. `^.*[A-Za-z].*$ # must contain a letter`

Comment: Does .NET support variable-width lookbehinds?

Comment: I don't believe so, though I'm not familiar with the concept.

Comment: Yes, .NET regexes support unknown-width lookbehinds.  At least, they do in .NET 3.5; whether they did in .NET 1.1, and whether it worked correctly, I couldn't say.

Comment: I see what you mean now (they are referred to as zero-width lookbehinds in .NET), and yes they are supported.

Comment: Actually, "zero-width" merely refers to the fact that they don't consume any characters; lookaheads, lookbehinds, word boundaries (`\b`) and anchors (`^`, `$`, `\A`, `\Z`, `\z`) are all zero-width assertions.  "Unknown-width" was my ill-advised attempt to abbreviate "able to match a variable number of characters, with no restrictions".  Java and PHP (PCRE) lookbehinds aren't limited to fixed-width matches like most other flavors', but they aren't completely unrestricted like .NET's lookbehinds either.

Comment: That's a good suggestion about the client-side validation. JavaScript regexes do support lookaheads (which is all the OP is using), but that support is notoriously inconsistent among the myriad browsers/versions.  And if your dual-validator idea doesn't work, it's time to get out the sledgehammer. :P

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried refactoring the regex?  For example:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_@+.-]{6,32}$).*[A-Za-z].*$
```

Or just "pad" your lookahead so it has to match all the way to the end:

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z].*$)[a-zA-Z0-9_@+.-]{6,32}$
```

Maybe that will reset the match position so the second part can start matching at the beginning.  It shouldn't be necessary, of course, but I can't see any reason why *your* regex wouldn't work as written.

Answer (score 0):

It's counting the lookahead after the digits because you allowed as much with

```
(?=.*[A-Za-z])
```

The `.*` means "after zero or more characters."

If you want to force a letter at the beginning, modify your pattern:

```
^[A-Za-z][-a-zA-Z0-9@_+.]{5,31}$
```

Comment: `(?= )` is a **zero width** positive lookahead assertion, so the "cursor" is being reset after the check.

Comment: He doesn't want to assert a letter at the start, only that the string *contains* a letter.

Comment: No probs! How'd the regex from my answer fair?

Comment: Then we're missing a piece of the puzzle somewhere. The example strings you gave all match the pattern from your question. Do your program's actual inputs, for example, contain more than than the 6- to 32-character fields?

Comment: But they don't match. Try it in .NET 1.1 in IE.